# Pevent CSS content property to be removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a form where I check the password strength of a user. It works correctly and shows the text according to the validation. But when a user makes a mistake and uses backspace to re-enter his password, the text from `data-text` isn't show anymore because the `content` property from the CSS is being removed (I guess because of the backspace). I couldn't find a solution to prevent it from being removed.

```js
// Password field
self.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  let val = self.value;
  testPasswordStrength(val);
});

// check password strength
const testPasswordStrength = (value) => {
  const strengthText = document.getElementsByClassName('js-password-strength')[0];
  const strongRegex = new RegExp(
      '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[=/\()%ยง!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})'
    ),
    mediumRegex = new RegExp(
      '^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{6,})'
    );

  if (value) {
    if (strongRegex.test(value)) {
      strengthText.setAttribute('data-validation-text', strengthText.dataset.textStrong);
      return "strong";
    } else if (mediumRegex.test(value)) {
      strengthText.setAttribute('data-validation-text', strengthText.dataset.textGood);
      return "medium";
    } else {
      strengthText.setAttribute('data-validation-text', strengthText.dataset.textDefault);
      return "weak";
    }
  } else {
    strengthText.classList.add("d-none");
  }
};
```

```css
content: attr(data-validation-text);
```

```html
<div class="js-password-strength" data-validation-text data-text-default="Password must be 8+ characters" data-text-good="Good password" data-text-strong="Great password">
</div>
```

Comment: Your current code seems to be working fine even after using the backspace key as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/gxryo6pc/10/

Comment: @AndrewL64 I found the solution and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndrewL64 I found the issue `strengthText.classList.add("d-none");` It makes it display none. So it removes the content property. So if the value is set. It should have `display: block`

```
 if (value) {
        strengthText.classList.remove("d-none");
        strengthText.classList.add("d-block");
        if (strongRegex.test(value)) {
            strengthText.setAttribute('data-validation-text', strengthText.dataset.textStrong);
            return "strong";
        } else if (mediumRegex.test(value)) {
            strengthText.setAttribute('data-validation-text', strengthText.dataset.textGood);
            return "medium";
        } else {
            strengthText.setAttribute('data-validation-text', strengthText.dataset.textDefault);
            return "weak";
        }
    } else {
        strengthText.classList.remove("d-block");
        strengthText.classList.add("d-none");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this work for you

```js
// Password field
const passwordField = document.getElementsByClassName('js-password-strength')[0];
passwordField.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
   let val = passwordField.textContent;
   testPasswordStrength(val);
});

// check password strength
const testPasswordStrength = (value) => {
;
    const strongRegex = new RegExp(
        '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[=/\()%ยง!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})'
        ),
        mediumRegex = new RegExp(
            '^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{6,})'
        );

    if (value) {
        if (strongRegex.test(value)) {
            passwordField.setAttribute('data-validation-text', passwordField.dataset.textStrong);
            return "strong";
        } else if (mediumRegex.test(value)) {
            passwordField.setAttribute('data-validation-text', passwordField.dataset.textGood);
            return "medium";
        } else {
            passwordField.setAttribute('data-validation-text', passwordField.dataset.textDefault);
            return "weak";
        }
    } else {
        passwordField.classList.add("d-none");
    }
};
```

```css
.js-password-strength{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.js-password-strength:after{
content: attr(data-validation-text);
font-size:12px;
color:#666;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="js-password-strength"
      data-validation-text
      data-text-default="Password must be 8+ characters"
      data-text-good="Good password"
      data-text-strong="Great password" contenteditable=true>
      </div>
   </body>
<html>
```